# Forcing Compile of .tag files

Tags: websphere, jstl, jsp-tags

How can I force Websphere to compile my .tag files?

Cleaning the project, publishing, restarting the server, adding and removing projects all don't help - the .class file for the tag file is not being recompiled.

If I delete the .class files, I get an error that the class is missing, but it does not recompile

Answer (score 3):

So far, my best answer is to delete the relevant contents of the /temp directory, for that war which resides under your server profile.  This will force a recompile of all jsp in the app, including the .tag files.

Answer (score 2):

I was having this same problem, then found this in an IBM technical journal on Websphere JSP implementation:

"Tag file source is compiled when the including JSP is processed by javac."

So I found that after each change to the .tag file, I had to make a change to the JSP that uses the tag.  (I would just add a space.) Then when the JSP is compiled, the .tag file is also successfully updated.

IBM Technical Journal article: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/techjournal/0412_johnson/0412_johnson.html

Comment: Worked for me. I had an include that was calling the tag.  This solved it.

Answer (score 0):

This might not help but there is an option during application install that you can tick to pre compile jsp pages, this may compile your .tag files

Karl